# How to change the timestamp to other time rather than utc time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

I'm working on an iiot based monitoring solution and working with aws services. I'm batching the data received from iot core in this flow: -

`iot core -> rules (to firehose delivery stream) -> kinesis firehose (900 second buffer) -> s3 bucket`

the s3 prefix is as follows:-

`partitionKey={partitionKeyFromQuery:device_name}/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:hh}`

but the issue with this flow is it makes the folder structure in s3 bucket as follows: -

`partitionKey=wind-mill-01/year=2023/month=01/day=08/hour=08 (logs hour in utc time)`

I want to log the time in ist format for the "hour" field is there any way possible to do it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don’t understand what you want, can you clarify please? Why don’t you connect iot rule to kinesis firehose directly?

Comment: I've done that already using iot rules my question is when i store the data as i mentioned above i get the "hour" part in utc timing i want it in IST if there is any way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firehose only support UTC as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/s3-prefixes.html). If you want to have it in IST for some reason, you can have a lambda (or glue job) moving object into another path with the hour in IST.